# Delete Azure Table Rows

Tags: .net, azure, logging, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to delete old azure logs, here is my code;

```
TableOperation tableOperation;
        CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = CosmosStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        foreach (var tableName in tableNames)
        {
            var table = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
            TableQuery query = new TableQuery().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThan, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-15).Date));
            try
            {
                var missing = 0;
                var oldRows = table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();
                var index = 0;
                while (index < oldRows.Count())
                {
                    if (oldRows[index] != null)
                    {
                        tableOperation = TableOperation.Delete(oldRows[index]);
                        await table.ExecuteAsync(tableOperation);
                        Debug.WriteLine(index);
                        index++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        missing++;
                        index++;
                    }
                }
                Debug.WriteLine($"{tableName} => Deleted : {index} , Missing : {missing}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var exception = e.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is i delete logs row by row and it takes so much time. I could apply batch operation to delete group by group but in my log table all rows have different partition key(I think this is a design mistake).Is there any other way to delete multiple rows instead deleting one by one even if all logs have different partition key?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ExecuteBatch()` methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.executebatchasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Table_CloudTable_ExecuteBatchAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Table_TableBatchOperation_) allow multiple delete operations with a few caveats that will require you to split the jobs into batches before executing it including splitting on partition key:

- Max 100 entities per request
- Each entity can only appear once
- All entities must have the same partition key
- Total payload can be no larger than 4 MiB
- List item

Within those limits, you can [mix and match transaction types](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-table-dotnet-getting-started/blob/42ca0b6d5ad4390423349594baceea3f5de38d3e/TableStorage/AdvancedSamples.cs#L328) so you could (if you wanted) delete, update, or insert within the same batch.

```
var oldRows = table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();

//Divide rows into batches by partition key and max size

foreach(var batch in batches) {
  
    // Create the batch operation. 
    TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
    
    foreach(var doc in batch)
    {
        batchOperation.Delete(doc);
    }

    // Execute the batch operation.
    IList<TableResult> results = await table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
    
    //deal with the results
}
```